# I expect John to x vs I expect John will x

Tags: phrases

1. I expect John **to** reply to your email.
2. I expect John **will** reply to your email.
3. I expect him **to** reply to your email
4. I expect him **will** reply to your email (ungrammatical)
5. I expect he **to** reply to your email (ungrammatical)
6. I expect he **will** reply to your email

Why do some of these sentences take *will* and others take *to*?

---

There is a question "Expect to" vs "Expect will". That post doesn't ask the question I've asked in this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your question is posed shows that you're thinking about it wrong.
It's **not** the case that "some of these sentences take *will* and others take *to*".

First, it's the ***Verb*** (not the sentence) that "takes" a [Complement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Complements.pdf), and every verb is different.

Second, *expect* can take both infinitive and tensed (*that*) complement clauses. Other verbs differ.

Third, the grammatical sentences with *will* above don't have *that*, but it's allowed --
these are correct, because *expect, think,* and *know* can all take tensed complement clauses:

- *I expect/think/know **that** [John will reply to your email].* (no. 1)
- *I expect/think/know **that** [he will reply to your email].* (no. 6)

so the complement clauses with *will* are tensed clauses, not infinitive clauses.
That means that the reason why you can't say no. 4 is that you must use *he* and not *him* in

- ***He*** will reply to your email.

Fourth, on the other hand, the complements with *to* are infinitive clauses, not tensed clauses.
*To* is a marker of an infinitive; it's not a verb but a complementizer, and it doesn't mean anything.
And the subject of an infinitive must be objective -- *him,* not *he* -- so that's the reason no. 5 is bad.
The sentence below works because *expect, tell,* and *want* can all take infinitive complement clauses:

- *I expect/told/want [**him** to close the window].*

This is a fact about the verb *expect*, by the way.
If you try the tensed (*that*) clause examples with *tell* or *want* instead, you'll get ungrammatical sentences, because *tell* and *want* **can't** take tensed clauses with *that*. And if you try the infinitive examples with *think* or *know*, the same thing will happen, because *think* and *know* can't take infinitive complements.

Grammar is not about words following words; grammar is about constituents, mostly clauses.
Get that right and the rest will follow.