# Why might the author have used "to be" instead of "is" in this sentence?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

> ...thinking **it to be** in the green box when **it is** really in the yellow box.

The *to be* does seem to suggest that the green box does not actually contain it. Is *to be*, as used in the quotation, a subjunctive construction? If it is, then is that construction the most appropriate subjunctive construction; why or why not?

Thank you.

Comment: It's the author's choice, since _think_ may take either [an infinitive or a tensed complement clause](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/169953/15299). They mean the same thing.

Comment: *To be* is here infinitive, not subjunctive. Using this option allows the writer to avoid picking a tense, between "is" and "was," for the counterfactual belief. Between condition contrary to fact and presumably reported thought (which grammatically resembles reported speech), your author may have tied herself a kind of grammatical Gordian Knot, and this is an easy way to cut it. (I'd know more were there more context given.)

Comment: @JohnLawler in the question you linked to, you commented "Grammar is not about words following words; grammar is about constituents, mostly clauses.
Get that right and the rest will follow." I've been meaning to ask if you could recommend a book that describes the constituents (or at least one system of them).

Comment: I doubt it's a "duplicate", FF. But there's certainly more discussion in the comments. As for references, @Hal, I'd recommend [McCawley 1998](http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/S/bo3613599.html).